# What tanks/armored vehicles are in these pictures?

Tags: world-war-two, military, 20th-century, identification, photograph

[image: WW2 Panzers]
[image: Two tanks in the foreground]
Need help in identifying the tanks/armored vehicles in the picture.
Date - 11 Aug 2019
Location - Birmenstorf, Switzerland
Event  - “[A Convoy to remember](https://www.convoy-to-remember.com/)” commemorating 75 Anniversary of WW2 Normandy DDay landing.

Comment: The one on the bottom right looks like a Swiss G-13 which was a version of the [Hetzer tank destroyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetzer) (Jagdpanzer 38)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I should have included more details. Amended the question now.

Comment: I'd guess that the one immediately behind the wooden stall is the Centurion and the one behind that is another Pz 68/88, with a M113 APC on the left.

Comment: Tank left of Hetzer could be some derivation of AMX-13 or Panzer 61. It looks more like Panzer 61, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

According to a page on the 'Convoy to Remember' site you linked, the one on the right is a G13, a post-war Swiss variant of the [Jagdpanzer 38 "Hetzer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetzer), and the one on the left is likely a [Panzer 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzer_68), a Swiss main battle tank developed in the late 1960's.

The description from Convoy to Remember can be found [here](https://www.convoy-to-remember.com/14-0-Panzer-Demo.html), and from the picture on that page you can see the same 'AH H' and 'M 78126' markings as in your picture:

> Panzerjäger G 13
>
> Czechoslovakia / Switzerland, from 1945-49. Manufactured: Diesel 86 Ex., Petrol 158 Ex. Weight: 16 t. 42 km / h. Versions with diesel or petrol engines. Diesel: Saurer 8-cylinder, 150 HP; Petrol: Skoda 6-cylinder, 160 HP. In use until 1973.

The one on the far left is less distinctive and doesn't have the same sort of ID numbers as the G13 in your picture, but from similar images I've found on the Convoy to Remember site and elsewhere it seems to be a Panzer 68. It's hard to tell because of the wood structure blocking them, but I believe the tanks in the background two more Panzer 68's.

Here's the description from the same page linked above, where you can also see a side view with the turret facing forward:

> Main battle tank 68/88
>
> Switzerland, 1970. 390 vehicles manufactured. 39 tons, 55 km / h. Drive: Mercedes-Benz 8-cylinder, 29,900 cc. In use until late summer 2002.

Finally, the covered truck driving past in the background is likely a [GMC CCKW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMC_CCKW_2%C2%BD-ton_6x6_truck), a truck produced in the US in large numbers during WWII.